# Freeing an entire linked list in C

Tags: c, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation, free, singly-linked-list

I know this question has been asked a lot on this site so I apologize for asking it again but I'm really stuck. I'm trying to create a function that deletes an entire linked list (in C). Any advice would really help me. I attached my current code for the function, the linked list structure, and the results on Valgrind.

```
typedef struct node {
    void* data;
    struct node* next;
} node_t;

typedef struct list {
    node_t* head;
    int (*comparator)(void*, void*);
    void (*printer)(void*);
    void (*deleter)(void*);
    int length;
} list_t;

void DestroyList(list_t* list) {
    if (list == NULL) return;
    struct list_t* curr;
    
    while (list != NULL) {
        curr = list;
        list = list->head->next;
        free(curr);
    }
}
```

Valgrind output:

```
[[ Valgrind Errors Detected ]]
==1045== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==1045== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==1045== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==1045== Command: ./main
==1045== Parent PID: 16
==1045== 
==1045== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==1045==    at 0x109DDC: DestroyList (hw2.c:123)
==1045==    by 0x10964F: _genos_unittest (DestroyList_small_list.c:30)
==1045==    by 0x109517: main (genos_unittest.h:173)
==1045== 
==1045== Invalid read of size 8
==1045==    at 0x109DDC: DestroyList (hw2.c:123)
==1045==    by 0x10964F: _genos_unittest (DestroyList_small_list.c:30)
==1045==    by 0x109517: main (genos_unittest.h:173)
==1045==  Address 0x2e2e2e35 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==1045== 
==1045== 
==1045== HEAP SUMMARY:
==1045==     in use at exit: 95 bytes in 8 blocks
==1045==   total heap usage: 10 allocs, 2 frees, 151 bytes allocated
==1045== 
==1045== 16 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 6 of 8
==1045==    at 0x4C31B0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==1045==    by 0x1095B0: _genos_unittest (DestroyList_small_list.c:17)
==1045==    by 0x109517: main (genos_unittest.h:173)
==1045== 
==1045== 16 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 7 of 8
==1045==    at 0x4C31B0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==1045==    by 0x10975A: InsertAtHead (linkedlist.c:54)
==1045==    by 0x109643: _genos_unittest (DestroyList_small_list.c:27)
==1045==    by 0x109517: main (genos_unittest.h:173)
==1045== 
==1045== 37 (16 direct, 21 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 8 of 8
==1045==    at 0x4C31B0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==1045==    by 0x10975A: InsertAtHead (linkedlist.c:54)
==1045==    by 0x1095A6: _genos_unittest (DestroyList_small_list.c:15)
==1045==    by 0x109517: main (genos_unittest.h:173)
==1045== 
==1045== LEAK SUMMARY:
==1045==    definitely lost: 48 bytes in 3 blocks
==1045==    indirectly lost: 21 bytes in 2 blocks
==1045==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1045==    still reachable: 26 bytes in 3 blocks
==1045==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1045== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==1045== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==1045== 
==1045== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==1045== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==1045== ERROR SUMMARY: 5 errors from 5 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Again, any help would really be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

`list` has type `list_t*`, but `list->head->next` has type `struct node*`. You should use a pointer with proper type to traverse the list.

It will be like this:

```
void DestroyList(list_t* list) {
    if (list == NULL) return;
    node_t* itr = list->head;
    node_t* curr;
    
    while (itr != NULL) {
        curr = itr;
        itr = itr->next;
        // if appropriate
        // free(curr->data);
        free(curr);
    }
    // if appropriate
    // free(list);
}
```

Comment: Types don't matter do they? `:)` Good additional comments.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. However, Valgrind is still 3 memory leaks for some reason. Do you think I need to free the comparator, printer, and deleter?

Comment: No. Functions will usually statically allocated in memory and won't be needed to be freed. This is "usually" and functions can also be stored on dynamically allocated memory, so I cannot definitely say about that without seeing what is assigned there.

Comment: @JohnWalling Make sure you close any files you open or `valgrind` will show that as an allocation that isn't freed.

Answer (score 1):

Your `DestroyList()` is implemented wrong (it should not even compile, as you are trying to assign a `struct node*` pointer to a `list_t*` pointer).

Try this instead:

```c
void DestroyList(list_t* list) {
    if (list == NULL) return;
    struct list_t *curr = list->head, *next;
    
    while (curr != NULL) {
        next = curr->next;
        free(curr);
        curr = next;
    }

    // depending on whether you want the list to be just cleared,
    // or actually destroyed, you need either:
    list->head = NULL;
    // or:
    free(list);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters it is unclear whether the data member `data` of the structure `struct node` points to a dynamically allocated object.

```
typedef struct node {
    void* data;
    struct node* next;
} node_t;
```

In general it should point to a dynamically allocated object.

Secondly an object of the type `struct list` can have automatic storage duration. So within the function `DestroyList` the pointer `list` shall not be used to free the pointed object of the type `struct list`.

Within the function you need to free all dynamically allocated nodes and other objects pointed to by the data member `data`.

After calling the function the list shall be a valid empty list.

And each list has only one object of the type `struct list`. So for example these lines

```
struct list_t* curr;
//...    
curr = list;
//...
free(curr);
```

do not make a sense.

So the function can be defined the following way

```
void DestroyList( list_t *list ) 
{
    while ( list->head != NULL ) 
    {
        node_t *curr = list->head;

        list->head = list->head->next;

        free( curr->data );
        free( curr );
    }

    list->length = 0;
}
```